# what is the right xdebug dll for PHP 5.3.27?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have tried 4 different xdebug dlls mentioned below, and none of them seem to work with netbeans as I continue to see the message "waiting for conection netbeans-xdebug":

```
php_xdebug-2.0.4-5.3.0-vc6
php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.2-vc9
php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.2-vc6
php_xdebug-2.1.0beta1-5.2-vc6
```

My php.ini contains the following:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension_ts = "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.2-5.3.0.dll"
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.2-5.3.0.dll"
extension = "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.2-5.3.0.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Comment: Which type of WAMP stack are you using? WAMP? EasyPHP? Something else?

Comment: I installed PHP, Apache, and netbeans software separately

Comment: Ok, which version of PHP are you using? VC9 I assume. Thread safe or non-thread safe?

Comment: PHP Extension Build API20090626,TS,VC9. thread safe

Comment: Ok, have you tried the DLLs on the xdebug site? http://xdebug.org/download.php

Comment: yes, I have tried several diferent ones. Bu I am not sure which one is the correct one for PHP 5.3.27 VC9. There are so many of them and none has label for PHP 5.3.27

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39860/discussion-between-user2070775-and-machavity)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

First, I needed to drop the lines

```
zend_extension_ts = "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.2-5.3.0.dll"
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.2-5.3.0.dll"
extension = "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.0.2-5.3.0.dll"
```

Machavity suggested to download php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9.dll from xdebug website. And then I updated the php.ini file with the following lines

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000

zend_extension = "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.3-vc9.dll"`
```

Note: PHP 5.3 does not like **zend_extension_ts**

I restarted Apache, and netbeans now connects to Xdebug.